# combine array elements into one element

Tags: r

I am reading an equation from shiny. I want to get the negative of this equation. Here is what I have, but it seems to return my answer as a 1x3 array rather than a 1x1 array.

```
Func <- as.character(input$ObjectiveFun)
```

which gives this:

```
"(x+2*y-7)^2+(2*x+y-5)^2"
```

Then I create the vector:

```
Func <- as.character(c("-(",Func,")"),sep="",collapse="",end="")
```

Which gives:

```
"-(" "(x+2*y-7)^2+(2*x+y-5)^2" ")"
```

But this is a chr[1:3]. I want this to only be one element or chr[1:1] for example:

```
"-((x+2*y-7)^2+(2*x+y-5)^2)"
```

I was thinking collapse would do that but it seems not. Any other ideas would be much appreciated :)

Comment: you seem to be missing `paste` in your example

Comment: @user20650 where would I add that? sorry this is my first time using r

Comment: `paste("-(", Func, ")", sep="", collapse="")`